# Data-attribute in Angular component

Tags: angular, angular-components, custom-data-attribute

I understand that I can add a data-attribute to an element within my component like this:

```
<div [attr.data-my]="myDataValue">
```

But how can I add a data-attribute to the component itself? I would expect to declare it like any other @Input, but I can't find any information about it? Does anyone know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following

```
@HostBinding('attr.data-my')
get someValue(): string {
   return this.myDataValue;
}
```

You can also add the `@HostBinding` above an `@Input` for brevity if it suits your use case - you'll find examples of that too